# Having two different resources on the same route path '/', in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a users and organizations in my app. I'd like to have the routes function like Github's where you essentially have both:

/john-doe

and

/johns-organization

What's the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ActiveRecord for data access and don't mind modifying the model,
then [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) or [Single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) should work.

Using the Single table inheritance idea we can have our model like:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class User < Resource; end
class Organization < Resource; end
```

and our the table like the following:

```
+----+----------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| id | Type           | Name              | Slug               |
+----+----------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| 1  | Users          | John Doe          | john-doe           |
| 2  | Organizations  | John Organization | johns-organization |
+----+----------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

then we should be able to access the resource with

```
resource = Resource.where(slug: 'john-doe').first
resource.type # user or organization
# which you can use to decide how to render the views accordingly.
```

Comment: Thanks for such a good answer. I was advised to not do STI so am looking to avoid that. 

If I understand well, from reading the link on Polymorphic Associations, the best way to do this would be to have a third resource ("Entity" for example), and have both Users and Organizations have many Entities?

Comment: That's correct, although Users and Organization should each `has_one` "Entity" instead of `has_many`.